# Why isn't my Redux action triggering the reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My code is supposed to update the time element on the screen and increase date on click of a button,  but that's not happening. I'm not sure what i'm missing here.

**actions.js**

```
export const getTime = () => {
    return ({
        type: "FETCH_TIME",
        payload: Date.now()
    });
};

export const incDate = (by) => {
    console.log("in inc date");
    return ({
        type : "INCREASE_DATE",
        payload : by
    });
};
```

**timeReducer.js**

```
const timeReducer = (state  = {
    time : Date.now(),
    date : 3
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_TIME":
            state = {
                ...state,
                time: action.payload
            };
            break
        case "INCREASE_DATE":
            state = {
                ...state,
                date : state.date + action.payload 
            };
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default timeReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  combineReducers
} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import logger from "redux-logger";
import {
  composeWithDevTools
} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import timeReducer from "../reducers/timeReducer";
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
  timeReducer
}), {}, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, promiseMiddleware, logger)));
export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you set up your reducer. Your reducer is supposed to be a function **that returns the new state**. It does not modify state that's passed as the argument with assignment, the key concept with Redux is immutability. Per [the Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions):

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and **returns the next state**.

And additionally:

> - **We don't mutate the `state`**. We create a copy with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). [...]
> - **We return the previous `state` in the `default` case**. It's important to return the previous state for any unknown action.

Thus, your reducer should look like this:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_TIME":
        return {
            ...state,
            time: action.payload
        };
    case "INCREASE_DATE":
        return {
            ...state,
            date : state.date + action.payload 
        };
    default:
        return state; 
}
```

In the snippet above, instead of doing `state = { ... }`, the reducer instead **returns the next state** of the application. The reducer also should, in a default case, just return the current state. You can get rid of the last `return`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, 
I initially tried this as well, it did not work.
The code never reaches the reducer file :(

Comment: @ManarjanSinghGhai Are you setting up your store correctly? Are you actually dispatching an action?

Comment: Basically actions are not getting triggered. Even the logger middleware isnt logging anything.

Comment: @ManarjanSinghGhai Really interesting... everything is setup correctly. Maybe get rid of all the middleware for right now and see what happens. That is really bizarre.

Comment: Wow. It worked ...  . I removed thunk and promise and it started working.

Comment: But i need them as I'm going to be working with api calls 

Comment: @ManarjanSinghGhai Now add them back one-by-one to isolate the one which is causing the problem. It might be a bug, or something weird going on.

Comment: redux-promise-middleware was the culprit.

Comment: nah. didn't work..
but i imported redux-promise instead of redux-promise-middleware now. and everyhing is working fine now.
I'm able to api calls as well through axios :)
but i keep getting 503 error on every second request